# How to map a directory from docker container to host?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container which has `/opt/boost/` directory. Is there any way that I can map it
to `/opt/boost` on my host machine and use its content?

Comment: Don’t expect Docker to copy data from container to the host when creating a bind mount. It doesn’t work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker `mount` with `bind` type.

```
docker run --mount type=bind,src=/opt/boost,destination=/opt/boost your_container:your_tag
```

Comment: It looks like my docker is too old "1.31.1" which doesn't support "--mount".